# Change the side menu's background image on mouseover using css

Tags: css, menu

I have a side menu in my web page.

Now I need to highlight selected menu using some color or a background image on mouseover using css. Is it possible? If possible how?

Comment: It's not possible in pure CSS. Does your menu expose some CSS selector that indicates the active one? (Like `<li class='selected'>`)

Comment: No it does not have any such thing... I just need to highlight on mouseover.. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for a change of style on mouseover, use the [:hover](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) pseudo selector.

```
a:hover {
   background-color: #FFF8B2;
}
```

Comment: I tried that... But only the text is getting highlighted. I want the whole list item to get highlighted

Comment: If u are not getting me... Just look at this website http://www.soldiers-league.com/vets